# How to parse and view properly with nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am having problems to view my xml data correctly. Here is my code in controller, and view.

```
  def new
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('sample3.xml'))

    @link = doc.xpath('//match').map do |t| {
      'home' => t.at('home').attr('name')
    }
  end

    @odds = doc.xpath('//odds/type[@name="1x2"]/bookmaker[@id="781"]').map do |t| {
      '1' => t.at('odd[@name="1"]').attr('value'),
      '2' => t.at('odd[@name="2"]').attr('value'),
      'X' => t.at('odd[@name="X"]').attr('value')
    }

  end
  end
  end
```

View:

```
<table class="flat-table">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <% @link.each do |t| %>
            <tr>

            <td><%= t['home'] %></td>

            <td> <%= t['1'] %> </td>
            <td> <%= t['2'] %> </td>
            <td> <%= t['X'] %> </td>
        </tr>
                <% end %>
```

My problem is, how can I show the value of @odds, as I have already put an "each do" code for @link? Thanks. and please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <match>
    <home name="Wembley"></home>
  </match>

  <match>
    <home name="Old Trafford"></home>
  </match>

  <odds>
    <type name="1x2">
      <bookmaker id="781">
        <odd name="1" value="10"></odd>
        <odd name="2" value="20"></odd>
        <odd name="X" value="30"></odd>
      </bookmaker>
    </type>
  </odds>

  <odds>
    <type name="1x2">
      <bookmaker id="781">
        <odd name="1" value="100"></odd>
        <odd name="2" value="200"></odd>
        <odd name="X" value="300"></odd>
      </bookmaker>
    </type>
  </odds>

</data>
```

code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(
  File.read('xml.xml')
)

links = doc.xpath('//match').map do |match|
  { 'home' => match.at('home').attr('name') }
end

my_xpath = '//odds/type[@name="1x2"]/bookmaker[@id="781"]' 

odds = doc.xpath(my_xpath).map do |bmaker|
  {
    '1' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="1"]').attr('value'),
    '2' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="2"]').attr('value'),
    'X' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="X"]').attr('value'),
  }
end
```

You could use a loop like this:

```
(0...links.size).each do |i|  #Note the 3 dots, which excludes the last.
  puts links[i]['home']

  puts odds[i]['1']
  puts odds[i]['2']
  puts odds[i]['X']

  puts '-' * 10
end

--output:--
Wembley
10
20
30
----------
Old Trafford
100
200
300
----------
```

Or, like this:

```
links.each_with_index do |link, i|
  puts link['home']

  puts odds[i]['1']
  puts odds[i]['2']
  puts odds[i]['X']

  puts '-' * 10
end
```

Or, like this:

```
links.each do |link|
  puts link['home']

  odd = odds.shift  #Remove first item from odds array. The other items shuffle to the left one position.
  puts odd['1']
  puts odd['2']
  puts odd['X']

  puts '-' * 10
end
```

But I prefer:

```
links_enum = links.each
odds_enum = odds.each

loop do   
  puts links_enum.next['home']  #The loop will end immediately if next() is called and there are no more items.

  odd = odds_enum.next   #The loop will end immediately if next() is called and there are no more items.
  puts odd['1']
  puts odd['2']
  puts odd['X']

  puts '-' * 10
end

--output:--
Wembley
10
20
30
----------
Old Trafford
100
200
300
----------
```

In your rails app, the action would like this:

```
#Get the xml from somewhere:
doc = Nokogiri::XML(
  File.read("#{Rails.root}/files/xml.xml")
)

links = doc.xpath('//match').map do |match|
  { 'home' => match.at('home').attr('name') }
end

my_xpath = '//odds/type[@name="1x2"]/bookmaker[@id="781"]' 

odds = doc.xpath(my_xpath).map do |bmaker|
  {
    '1' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="1"]').attr('value'),
    '2' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="2"]').attr('value'),
    'X' => bmaker.at('odd[@name="X"]').attr('value'),
  }
end

#Set the view variables:
@links_enum = links.each
@odds_enum = odds.each
```

Then your view would like this:

```
<table class="flat-table">
<tbody>

<% loop do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @links_enum.next['home'] %></td>

    <% odd = @odds_enum.next %>
    <td> <%= odd['1'] %> </td>
    <td> <%= odd['2'] %> </td>
    <td> <%= odd['X'] %> </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

</tbody>
</table>
```

But use whichever loop makes the most sense to you.  :)

**Response to comment**:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(
  open("http://www.tipgin.net/example-data/odds-worldcup-example.xml")
)

match_xpath = '/odds/league/matches/match[./odds/type]'

doc.xpath(match_xpath).each do |match|
  puts match.at_xpath("./home")['name']
  puts 'vs.'
  puts match.at_xpath("./away")['name']

  match.xpath('./odds/type/bookmaker').each do |bmaker|
    puts bmaker['name']

    bmaker.xpath('./odd').each do |odd|
      puts "#{odd['name']} ... #{odd['value']}"
    end

    break
  end
  break
end

--output:--
Brazil
vs.
Croatia
12Bet
1 ... 1.27
2 ... 9.56
X ... 5.32
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer :) What if my xml structure is like this:

Comment: can you help me have a look at this http://www.tipgin.net/example-data/odds-worldcup-example.xml, where some of the matches do not have odds, and some have odds, how to I filter to select only those with odds? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <td> <%= @odds[0]['1'] %> </td>
       <td> <%= @odds[0]['2'] %> </td>
       <td> <%= @odds[0]['X'] %> </td>
```

To display first entry. Or iterate inside loop, whatever.

Are you sure you do understand what you are doing?

Comment: No, I mean is there a way that I can add "each do" method to odds together with link?

Comment: Cos I want to loop through odds too. or can I add odds and links into 1 variable in the controller?